# Applying jQuery UI Sortable to hundreds of elements on a page results in very slow page load -- need ideas on how to make it more efficient

Tags: jquery-ui, calendar, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm building a drag and drop calendar and have found that jQuery UI's sortable offers the best live performance for what I'm trying to do.

However, applying sortable to many months worth of days (60 to 180 days at a time -- sometimes more) results in a noticeable lag upon page load as my script is applying all those sortable instances. It works fine once it's loaded, but I'd rather not have the initial lag. In some cases the browser even tries to kill the script.

I tried making the first day of the calendar sortable and then using jQuery's .clone() to copy to all the other days, but unfortunately jQuery's .clone() doesn't appear to copy .sortable's events. Other events (such as click, double click, etc) get copied fine, but not sortable. Doing some research online, all I could find was the statement that jQuery "doesn't support cloning of plugins."

Is there a better way to do this? I've scoured stackoverflow, jQuery UI's forums, and Google in general, and have found nothing of help.

Thanks in advance,
Jamon

EDIT: Here is some code. Nothing too special.

```
    function sortableStop(event, ui) {
              // Saves to the DB here. Code removed - not relevant
    }

    $(".milestone-day").bind("dblclick", function(ev) {
      // Allows adding milestones. Code removed - not relevant
    }).sortable({
        handle: '.handle',
        connectWith: '.milestone-day',
        items: '.milestone',
        stop: sortableStop
    });
```

The markup looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><ul class="milestone-day"></ul></td>
      <td><ul class="milestone-day"></ul></td>
      <td><ul class="milestone-day"></ul></td>
      <td><ul class="milestone-day"></ul></td>
      <td><ul class="milestone-day"></ul></td>
      <td><ul class="milestone-day"></ul></td>
      <td><ul class="milestone-day"></ul></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><ul class="milestone-day"></ul></td>
      <td><ul class="milestone-day"></ul></td>
      <td><ul class="milestone-day"></ul></td>
      <td><ul class="milestone-day"></ul></td>
      <td><ul class="milestone-day"></ul></td>
      <td><ul class="milestone-day"></ul></td>
      <td><ul class="milestone-day"></ul></td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Milestones are li elements loaded into their proper milestone-day uls via ajax.

<del>EDIT 2: Working demo posted:</del>

http://www.clearsightstudio.com/demos/calendar-load/

EDIT 3: Demo is gone. Sorry.

Note that there's a lag when you open the page. There's a lot more going on than on that demo in my actual app, so the lag is even more noticeable.

Comment: Can you post some code so that we can help you optimize it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Tim. Posted the code above. There are usually 120 or more "milestone-day" ul tags, so the $(".milestone-day") jQuery objects get .sortable() applied many times over.

Comment: Stumped Stackoverflow? Didn't think that was possible. :)

Answer (score 6):

call the connectWith after call the sortable(), example:

```
$('.whatever').sortable().sortable( "option", "connectWith", '.whatever' );
```

for some reason it improved the performance a LOT in my scenario (thousands of elements)

Comment: It does improve the performance a ton! It's being very buggy for me, though -- can't seem to get it to work quite right. Like the elements "drop out" when I'm trying to drag them sometimes.

Comment: That's a bug I guess, I tried connectwith as normal inside the sortable() and it hangs and freezes around. 
When doing it like you suggested it's quick without any freezes...

Answer (score 2):

try not to bind all the elements onload do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(".milestone").live("mouseenter", function(){
                function sortableStop(event, ui) {
                    alert("Sortable stop fired!");
                }

                $($(this).parent()).bind("dblclick", function() {
                    alert("Double-click fired!");
                }).sortable({
                    connectWith: '.milestone-day',
                    items: '.milestone',
                    stop: sortableStop
                });
            });
        </script>
```

this will improve the performance

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P27qv/

Comment: Hm, that's an interesting approach. I will play around with it and see if this works.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with hundreds of images that needed to be draggable. and initialization just took too much time

I was able to solve it by lazy instantiation upon mouseenter, it works great, and the user experience is not changed

See more info here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20399896/287455

Answer (score 0):

Move your code to bind all the controls out of the page load event.
It won't be any faster but it will appear faster to the user.
You might also change the code and markup so the individual items are disabled on load
and after their events are bound they're enabled. This will prevent fast twitch
users from clicking on them and wondering why nothing happened.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Jay. Are you suggesting to put the jQuery code into the $(document).ready() event? It actually already is, so the document loads and then "freezes" while the sortables are being initialized. The user isn't able to click on anything while that's happening.

If I get time I'll post a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it a lot faster if I hide the sortables before I call .sortable(). But, it only made a huge difference on the iPad Safari. For other browsers, it was pretty much the same.

Example code:

```
$(".milestone-day").hide()

$(".milestone-day").sortable({
    handle: '.handle',
    connectWith: '.milestone-day',
    items: '.milestone',
    stop: sortableStop
});

$(".milestone-day").show()
```