# jQuery UI .sortable() call is slow when applies to thousands of elements

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

My issue is basically this - [Applying jQuery UI Sortable to hundreds of elements on a page results in very slow page load -- need ideas on how to make it more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873840/applying-jquery-ui-sortable-to-hundreds-of-elements-on-a-page-results-in-very-sl) but since none of the answers solved my problem, I'm asking the question again.

Applying .sortable() on 300 elements (http://jsfiddle.net/LcgEL/) takes about 60ms. Applying it to thousands of element results in times approaching 250ms. This introduces a very noticeable delay that affects the user experience as it appears the application is laggy.

Is there any way to speed this up? Thanks!

```
JSFiddle link for the code - http://jsfiddle.net/LcgEL/
```

Comment: How about not applying it to thousand of elements and use some kind of pagination instead?

Comment: you could try sorting the items in segments,so that the performance will improve a bit

Comment: I wouldn't do that, because of the problem you are dealing with at the moment. Instead, you can try to (a) solve the problem with a pagination or (b) sort your stuff BEFORE they are added to the DOM. For example, use PHP to sort them or sort your (Backbone) objects etc.

Comment: With window.performance.now(). It is getting slow / not sorting.

Comment: Our application is a Kanban type project management tool and so pagination would not be applicable. Users often have x00s of cards on their board. In addition to sortable cards, the cards are also droppable so those two combined take about 250ms in total when the user hits about 300 cards which results in a very noticeable lag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

a tough one, I had a similar problem with hundreds of images that needed to be draggable. and initialization just took too much time

I was able to solve it by lazy instantiation upon mouseenter, it works great, and the user experience is not changed

Here is how it could be done with sortable: (http://jsfiddle.net/q8ND4/3/)

```
var $sortable1 = $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
  items: ".sorting-initialize" // only insert element with class sorting-initialize
});
$sortable1.find(".ui-state-default").one("mouseenter",function(){
  $(this).addClass("sorting-initialize");
  $sortable1.sortable('refresh');
});
```

In your example it decreases the time from 30ms to 8ms.

**Another improvement:**
The next step will be to move the mouseenter handler binding to the point in code when you append these `<li>` to the list (if this is done via js on the client side)

Comment: Sadly, this only works if you have hovered the element you want to interact with. In the case of a drag and drop, if the cursor stay in the boundaries of the dragged element, there is no initialization of the other elements. You can easily reproduce with a slow drag and drop (cursor stay in dragged element boundaries => no initialization of other elements) vs a fast drag and drop (cursor get out of dragged element boundaries => initialization of other elements).

Comment: I am able to get @ekeren's solution to work, and unable to get the downside mentioned above. Either I am not doing the negative testing very well (to see if the uninitialized elements cause me issues), or the issue will be unnoticeable by my users. Either way, until this issue pops up for me, I am keeping my fingers crossed that it continues to work for me! This answer is 10 years old, and still works in 2023 for me. Thanks @ekeren!

Comment: Thanks @KobusMyburgh, it has been a while indeed... haven't worked on jquery not frontend stuff for a decade already

Answer (score 19):

If anyone stumbles on this page because they upgraded to 1.12.1 like me and hit the performance issue:
Instead of rolling back to 1.11.4, find the `_setHandleClassName` function in the sortable widget (in my custom download around line #5300 in `jquery-ui.js`) and change:

```js
$.each( this.items, function() {
    that._addClass(
        this.instance.options.handle ?
        this.item.find( this.instance.options.handle ) :
        this.item,
        "ui-sortable-handle"
    );
});
```

To:

```js
$.each( this.items, function() {
    (this.instance.options.handle 
     ? this.item.find( this.instance.options.handle ) 
     : this.item
    ).addClass('ui-sortable-handle');
});
```

Like it was in the previous version.

For my case this sped up the initialization of a sortable list of 700 items from ~20 seconds to some milliseconds. o_O

Do note: While I haven't seen any issues yet using this approach for my page, it hasn't been thoroughly tested due to lack of time.

Comment: This fixed it for me.  There is an open Jquery UI bug ticket that has not been acknowlegded here: https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/15097

Comment: I've created a pull request to merge your suggestion (see https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/pull/2063)

Answer (score 11):

You should roll back your version of jQuery UI to version 1.11.4
https://jqueryui.com/download/all/

After struggling with this for a few days that was the only thing that helped me. I have about 800 entries being sorted between 6 lists. Using UI v1.12.1 my page was taking about 20 seconds to load. After switching to v1.11.4 my page load time was closer to 5 seconds.

I tried the solution by ekeren which partially worked, but elements that hadn't been initialized weren't in the 'sorting order' so you could only interact with elements that had already been hovered over.

Comment: I can confirm this. version 1.12.1 is ultra slow and 1.11.4 is normal.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was the CSS3 `transition: all` property set on the sortable elements due to an erroneous comma:

```
.item {
    transition: flex-basis ease 200ms, margin ease, 200ms;
    //                                       here ^
}
```

which basically equates to `transition: all 200ms;`

I mistakenly put a comma after `ease` after the `margin ease,`, removing the comma and restoring the transitions to just being on margin and flex-basis fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you proceed with @e-benzle suggestion and run the latest JQuery version (v3.3.1), which is the best solution so far (in my opinion), you will have to replace the following function call in the jquery-ui.js v1.11.14 script with the one from version 1.12.1 because of the errors `withinElement.offset()` will throw.

**Function from v1.12.1**

```
getWithinInfo: function( element ) {
        var withinElement = $( element || window ),
            isWindow = $.isWindow( withinElement[ 0 ] ),
            isDocument = !!withinElement[ 0 ] && withinElement[ 0 ].nodeType === 9,
            hasOffset = !isWindow && !isDocument;
        return {
            element: withinElement,
            isWindow: isWindow,
            isDocument: isDocument,
            offset: hasOffset ? $( element ).offset() : { left: 0, top: 0 },
            scrollLeft: withinElement.scrollLeft(),
            scrollTop: withinElement.scrollTop(),
            width: withinElement.outerWidth(),
            height: withinElement.outerHeight()
        };
    }
```