# jQuery Sortable very slow

Tags: jquery

i have sortable problem in jquey. In case of 1000 records, the page takes about 5 seconds to load.
Can it be optimized?

Ultimately, the database will have 4,000 records

```
<tbody class="row_position">
            <?php
                    while($user = $users->fetch_assoc()){
                ?>
                    <tr id="<?php echo $user['id'] ?>">
                        <td><?php echo $user['id'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $user['gid'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $user['name'] ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php 
                    } 
                ?>
                </tbody>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".row_position").sortable({
        delay: 150,
        stop: function() {
            var selectedData = new Array();
            $('.row_position>tr').each(function() {
                selectedData.push($(this).attr("id"));
                
            });
            
            updateOrder(selectedData);
          
        }
    });
    function updateOrder(data) {
        $.ajax({
            url:"ajaxPro.php",
            type:'post',
            data:{position:data},
            success:function(data){
                toastr.success('Your Change Successfully Saved.');
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The problem was jQuery version 1.12.1 I changed to version 1.11.4 and it works fine.

This thread also describes how changing the jQuery version changes performance:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398400/jquery-ui-sortable-call-is-slow-when-applies-to-thousands-of-elements)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Your are doing it wrong.

Problems:

1. Your are doing client side processing. You should use server side processing.
2. You are fetching all the records which will slow down the serve maybe crash it due to bandwidth.

There are 2 solutions 1st one is Complex and 2nd is easy:

Solution 1:
Write your own jQuery which interact with PHP and get first 10, 20 or maximum 50 records. Add pagination so when you click on 2 tab in the pagination it will fetch next 10, 20 or maximum 50 record. You also have to write your own query to sort the table.

Solution 2:
Use Data Tables to handle these things also do it in server side processing I am mentioning links below which can help you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCAMMB-2B2Q&ab_channel=PhpflowLabs
https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/large_js_source.html

Comment: 1. The question relates to an UI component (jQuery UI - sortable). Why should the server be involved to something other then fetching the data? 2. Fetching 1000 records should be easy for any server. If it's not you probably have bigger issues. 3. This is not really an answer but an advice at best.

Comment: Hi Mark, with due respect as you know we are discussing about the speed so as then server side processing will be involved in this scenario hope you understand my point.

Comment: It is a bit unclear because the OP does not provide a good example, but he says the performance problem is with the sortable plugin wich is a client side ui component.

Comment: I think sorting 1000 records is the main issue he/she is fetching almost every record from database as you can see in his/her code and also telling that there is 4,000 plus records in database so I think problem is clear it will be solve using server side processing

Comment: Sorting 1000 records should be easy for any sorting algorithm (accept algorithms like Bogosort). I admit it does not sounds ideal to get all 1000 records here, but we don't know the use case so it might just be needed. The quantity should not be a problem at all. As pointed out by the OP it seemed to be the jQuery version which confirms it was a 100% client sided problem.

Comment: Exactly that's what I am saying